# How can I add the value (not just the percentage) to an Excel pie chart?

Tags: c#, excel, charts, excel-interop, excel-charts

I've got this code:

```
private void WriteChartSheet()
{
    _xlSheetChart = (Worksheet)_xlSheets.Item[2];

    if (_xlSheetChart != null)
    {
        _xlSheetChart.Name = ProduceUsageChartSheetName;
        // Contract vs. non-Contract pie chart 
        _xlSheetChart.Cells[1, 1] = "Contracted Items";
        _xlSheetChart.Cells[1, 2] = "Non-Contracted Items";
        _xlSheetChart.Cells[2, 1] = GetContractedItemsTotal();
        _xlSheetChart.Cells[2, 2] = GetNonContractedItemsTotal();

        ChartObjects xlCharts = (ChartObjects)_xlSheetChart.ChartObjects(Type.Missing);
        ChartObject contractChartObject = xlCharts.Add(0, 0, 300, 250); // left, top, width, height
        Chart contractChart = contractChartObject.Chart;

        Range chartRange = _xlSheetChart.get_Range("A1", "B2");
        contractChart.SetSourceData(chartRange, Missing.Value);
        contractChart.ChartType = XlChartType.xlPie;  //xl3DPie;
        contractChart.ApplyDataLabels(XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowLabel, true, false, false, true, false, true);
        . . .
```

...that produces this pie chart:

[image]

I like it well enough, but I need to have the value printed within the pie pieces, too (such as "$361,779" for the "Contracted Items" piece, and the appropriate value for the other, also). How can I do that?

Comment: Not sure how to do it with C#, but in Excel, select the chart, go to Layout, then "Data Labels", and choose where you want them.

Comment: I need to do it in code - is that what you mean? I have this already:
contractChart.ApplyDataLabels(XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowLabel, true, false, false, true, false, true);
...but it only gives me the %

Comment: Ah, I think you just have to change one of your `True/False`.  Check out [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.applydatalabels.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, the "true/false" is what's determining what value is showing:

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.chart.applydatalabels.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1):

```
void ApplyDataLabels(
    XlDataLabelsType Type = XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue,
    object LegendKey,
    object AutoText,
    object HasLeaderLines,
    object ShowSeriesName,
    object ShowCategoryName,
    object ShowValue,
    object ShowPercentage,
    object ShowBubbleSize,
    object Separator
)
```

So, adjust the `True` and `False` as applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Experimenting with Batman's info, I came up with this:

```
contractChart.ApplyDataLabels(XlDataLabelsType.xlDataLabelsShowValue, false, true, false, false, false, true, true, false, false);
```

...that produces this:

[image]

I would prefer to not have the leading "0" in the percentages (it is displaying "045" and "055" rather than the more sensible and economical "45" and "55"), but I can live with them.

Comment: Just a thought, does the data that the percentage represents have extra digits? Maybe if you edit the format of those numbers it'll work. Or try right clicking the data after there chart is created and adjust to two digits?